# How to attach source files to their eclipse plugin dependency jars to view the javadocs?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When developing a java application, we can attach the source files/jars to their library jars to generate/view the javadocs viewable in the tooltips. When developing eclipse plugins, I want to do the same with the plugin dependency jars. I want to attach the source files/jars to their plugin dependency jars to generate/view the javadocs during development as tooltips. How can I do that?

Comment: Make sure the corresponding source features are contained in the target platform.

Comment: Eclipse plug-ins usually have a separate 'source' plug-in, so `org.eclipse.core.runtime` has a matching `org.eclipse.core.runtime.source`. As long as the source plug-in is available in the target platform (or workspace) Eclipse will find it and use it for the source.